# How do I change the bulb on my kichler ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan, light-bulb

The light burned out in my Kichler ceiling fan, which came with my new house, so I have no idea how old it is or any other information about it.
I can't figure out how to get at the bulb to change it. I've tried gently turning the glass counter clockwise, as recommended in another post, but no luck.
Does anyone know how to do this?
thanks
[image]

Comment: Have you tried pulling straight down?

Comment: I know you said you turned it gently but it may require more force than gentle, frosted glass can be less then smooth.  It may be that you need to push up on it while turning.  Counter clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/999903421_install.pdf

Page 9/10

Looks like it twists off. Like others said try a bit more force or slightly push up to get it started.